# Extra field in intent to open a given Gmail label

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail

I know all this is not documented...

After analyzing GmailWidgetPlus code, I'm trying to use an intent to launch Gmail with a specific label (testing it with QCustomShortcut and Launcher Pro Shortcuts). Right now I accomplished the following:

```
Action: android.intent.action.VIEW
Package: com.google.android.gm
Class: com.google.android.gm.ConversationListActivityGmail
Extra1: "label", "^f"
Extra2: "account", "xxx@xxx"
```

This actually works -- it opens Gmail app in the account "xxx@xxx" with the "Sent" label. `"^f"` is a standard Gmail alias for the "Sent" label. Other alias also work.

However, I do not know how to change `Extra1` to open any user label (with a `"^x"` alias not predefined by Gmail). For example, if the label is named "Work" placing "Work" in Extra1 instead of `"^f"` gives the error: "The label does not exists".

Which is the correct syntax to specify a normal label in the intent?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution looking at the file 
"/dbdata/databases/com.google.android.gm/mailstore.xxx@xxx", which is the sqlite3 database where Gmail stores the label info (among other things). Inside this database, if inspected with a database viewer app (for example, Root Explorer does the job), the table "labels" contains the correct label name in the column "canonicalName".